# Eclipselink inserting entity with 0 ID

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I just discovered a rather strange problem with EclipseLink (both 2.3.0 and 2.4.1) and just wanted to ask if anyone can confirm that this is a bug and not just that I am missing something obvious ...

Basically, I have two entities involved, let us simply call them A and B. A had an eager (if that matters), non-cascading many-to-one unidirectional reference to B modelled in the database with a join column. The DB table A contains the columns ID (PK), B_ID (FK to B.ID), and more, the table B contains the columns ID and a few more.

Now, I had a list of As, which should be updated with references to new B instances. In pseudo-code something like:

```
for(A a : list) {
    // using some criteria, check if perhaps a matching B
    // entity is already found in the database
    B b = perhapsGetExistingBFromDatabase();

    if(b == null) {
        // no existing B was found, create a new
        b = new B();
        // set values in B
        b.setFoo(4711),
        b.setBar(42);

        // save B
        em.merge(b);
    }

    // set reference from A to B ...
    a.setB(b);
    // ... and update A
    em.merge(a);
}
```

Since the reference was non-cascading, it was necessary to merge both b and a. Everything worked as expected.

Then, someone (I) changed the cascade type of the relationship from none to merge/persist, since that was required somewhere else in the code. I expected the old code to work, merging b is not really required, shouldn't IMHO however hurt? A brief test confirmed that it still worked, the new B entity was inserted and A updated accordingly.

BUT, it only works if there is only one A entity in the list. Running through the loop a second time causes EclipseLink to auto-flush the session since `perhapsGetExistingBFromDatabase` does a "SELECT .. FROM B", there is a merged B entity cached and it wants the database table to be up to date. Using FINEST logging level and breakpoints in the code, I can verify that EclipseLink determines that it is required to generate an id for the new B entity, it invokes the sequence generator and also sets the id in the correct field of the entity. Still, EclipseLink invokes SQL statements similar to these:

```
INSERT INTO B (ID, ...) VALUES(0, ...);
UPDATE A SET B_ID = 0 WHERE ID = ...;
```

The generated id is lost somewhere and EclipseLink tries to create a new entity with id=0. The data is indeed invalid and later, EclipseLink also throws a PersistenceException: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone.

Bug or my mistake?

---

Edit: James asked for the mapping of B.ID:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sq_idgen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_idgen", sequenceName = "...", allocationSize = 100)
@Column(name = "id")
protected long id;
```

Note, that removing the unneccesary `em.merge(b);` solves my problem. It is just not obvious to me why the invocation of merge causes EclipseLink to fail completely, trying to insert a B instance without a populated id.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd, how is the Id of B mapped?

Seems like the merged might somehow be getting two separate instances of B (as there is nothing to identify them as being the same as they have no Id). Not that merge() is normally not required, it is only required for detached objects, such as when using serialization (try using persist instead).

To avoid the flush you can set the flushMode in the EntityManager or persistence unit to COMMIT instead of AUTO.

Comment: I've added the id-mapping to my original question. Merging b was in this case actually required, since it was a new object. If I had persisted it, its id would not have been immediately updated and I couldn't have connected it with the existing a instance. Automatic flush mode is also correct in this case, since I may create new instances of B, which can be found by `perhapsGetExistingBFromDatabase` in later loop iterations.